# Making a copy of a site

Tags: html, css, copy, padding

I was tring to make a copy of this site using html and css for practise
https://www.raidhqgame.com/
But I found some problems while using padding in the menuArea div.

**HTML**

```
<header> 
    <div class="head1"> 
        <div class="logoArea">
            <img id="logo" src="https://www.raidhqgame.com/images/RHQ_Logo_680x200.png" alt="RAID_HQ LOGO"/>
        </div>
    <div class="menuArea">
        <a href="#">HOME</a>
        <a href="#">FEATURES</a>
        <a href="#">VIDEO & SCREENS</a>
        <a href="#">REVIEWS</a>
        <a href="#">DOWNLOAD</a>
        <a href="#">HELP</a>
        <a href="#">EPS</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="background_img"> 
    <img src="https://www.raidhqgame.com/images/RAID_Web_BG_01_1500x800.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.head1{
    height:60px;
    background:black;
}
.logoArea{
    float:left;
    width:40%
}
#logo{
    height:40px;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 110px;
}
.menuArea{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:60%;
}
a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: green;
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

**The problem**: when I add padding to the menuArea div the menuArea jumps down. And also there is a gap between "head1" class and "background_img" class. 
How can I resolve these two issues?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might get the desired effect by adding padding to the head1 div instead of the menuArea.

Here is your updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/ntb7nt39/

**CSS**

```
.head1{
    height:60px;
    background:black;
    padding: 20px; // You should change this value to whatever you want
}
```

'*And also there is a gap between "head1" class and "background_img" class.*' I could not recreate that gap.

**UPDATE**
*'I want to have padding for the menu section. Not the whole head1.'*
I updated the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ntb7nt39/1/

**CSS**

```
.head1{
    height: 80px; // Increased height to make space for the navigation bar
    background:black;
}

.menuArea{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:60%;
    padding: 20px 0; // Added padding at the top and bottom of the navigation bar, change these values according to your needs.
}
```

Comment: I want to have padding for the menu section.not the whole head1

Comment: could you post a screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ImrulKayes I updated the code in my answer. Could you please have a look if that is what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can just remove the width=60% from class menuArea and than you will be able to add any kind of padding or
2. use top and bottom padding only, no left right padding because you covered the full 100% width by setting 40% 60% and when you add left right padding to it increases the width which leads to this issue.

and for second issue add height:100% to logoArea class.